# Issue Restarting Standby Server PostgreSQL V13 Window Server

Tags: postgresql, windows-server

When I try to start PostgreSQL standby Server below mentioned log file is continuously generating and resorting the same log files. Can some one has the idea why Database is continuously working the same logs files

```
2021-06-17 13:34:51.906 +03 [9808] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000820000003C" from archive
2021-06-17 13:34:51.948 +03 [9808] LOG:  invalid record length at 82/3C000688: wanted 24, got 0
2021-06-17 13:34:55.949 +03 [8572] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 82/3C000000 on timeline 1
2021-06-17 13:34:55.957 +03 [8572] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000000820000003C has already been removed
2021-06-17 13:34:56.904 +03 [9808] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000820000003C" from archive
2021-06-17 13:34:56.946 +03 [9808] LOG:  invalid record length at 82/3C000688: wanted 24, got 0
2021-06-17 13:35:00.749 +03 [9012] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 82/3C000000 on timeline 1
2021-06-17 13:35:00.756 +03 [9012] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000000820000003C has already been removed
2021-06-17 13:35:01.913 +03 [9808] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000820000003C" from archive
2021-06-17 13:35:01.973 +03 [9808] LOG:  invalid record length at 82/3C000688: wanted 24, got 0
2021-06-17 13:35:05.399 +03 [8660] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 82/3C000000 on timeline 1
2021-06-17 13:35:05.420 +03 [8660] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000000820000003C has already been removed
2021-06-17 13:35:06.925 +03 [9808] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000820000003C" from archive
2021-06-17 13:35:06.973 +03 [9808] LOG:  invalid record length at 82/3C000688: wanted 24, got 0
2021-06-17 13:35:10.199 +03 [8496] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 82/3C000000 on timeline 1
2021-06-17 13:35:10.212 +03 [8496] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000000820000003C has already been removed
2021-06-17 13:35:11.916 +03 [9808] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000820000003C" from archive
2021-06-17 13:35:11.971 +03 [9808] LOG:  invalid record length at 82/3C000688: wanted 24, got 0
2021-06-17 13:35:15.320 +03 [7672] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 82/3C000000 on timeline 1
2021-06-17 13:35:15.335 +03 [7672] FATAL:  could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000000820000003C has already been removed
2021-06-17 13:35:16.915 +03 [9808] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000820000003C" from archive
2021-06-17 13:35:16.962 +03 [9808] LOG:  invalid record length at 82/3C000688: wanted 24, got 0
```

Comment: Looks like that log file is corrupted in the archive.  You will probably need to recreate the standby, unless you have another copy of it someplace.

Answer (score 0):

The `invalid record length` message itself is harmless, it indicates that there is no more WAL to be found.

I can think of two reasons:

- the downtime was long enough that the primary really doesn't have the information any more (look for a file ending with `000000820000003C` in `pg_wal`)

  In that case, rebuild the standby.
- the timeline has switched because the primary was promoted, but the standby doesn't have `recovery_target_timeline = latest`, so it does not follow the timeline switch

  In that case, change the setting and restart.

Comment: When I changed the Standby Server setting to recovery_target_timeline = latest and then bounce back server and  still receiving the same logs doing same the same thing

Comment: 2021-06-17 14:39:11.304 +03 [9096] LOG:  restored log file "00000001000000820000003C" from archive
2021-06-17 14:39:11.358 +03 [9096] LOG:  invalid record length at 82/3C000688: wanted 24, got 0